# How to read .wav file as byte array in android studio?

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I am using Java in android studio to write my application. I have a file path to an audio file (in .wav format), What would be the best method to read the .wav file into a byte array?
I am using the following conversion method:

```
public void open_audio_file(Uri filePath){
        try{
            in = new BufferedInputStream(getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePath));

            int read;
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
            {
                out.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        //Todo : Change the audio file to a float pointer
        audioBytes = out.toByteArray();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"The audio file is " + audioBytes.toString());
    }
```

However, this method produces a lot of jargon values that are not read by my function. For example, the output of dog.wav [www.beaniebestbuy.com/sounds/dog5.wav](http://www.beaniebestbuy.com/sounds/dog5.wav) was [B@d25663f . There are jargon values attached to the beginning of the array.

Update 1 : I tried to use the AudioSystem library, but it is not supported in Android studio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a .WAV audio data sample into an double type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957850/how-to-convert-a-wav-audio-data-sample-into-an-double-type)

Comment: @Jason Not really, I am trying to convert it to a byte array, however, there are some jargon values associated with the output. For example, after conversion of the (dog.wav)[www.beaniebestbuy.com/sounds/dog5.wav], the first value is : [B@d25663f.

Comment: `[B@d25663f` is the `toString()` of an array, `[B` indicates it is a byte array, and `d25663f` is the hexadecimal form of the (identity) hash code of the array. I'm not sure what you expect `audioBytes.toString()` to do.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, the first answer verified that what I was doing was correct. Thank you for the additional clarification.

Comment: @KarunDawadi I am trying to read data from WAV file. Have you done it?

Comment: @AfaqKhan unfortunately I was not able to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the file correctly. Since you're just reading bytes, the file type is actually irrelevant.

When you call `toString` on an array, it doesn't give you a representation of the entire array, it just gives you the object reference. See [documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

If you want to see the full array, you'll need to use a `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < audioBytes.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(audioBytes[i] +" ");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Arrays.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte%5B%5D))

Do note that this will probably be a very large output, not likely to be easily readable.

Comment: Thank you, I am not so familiar with .wav file format. Seeing the jargon values freaked me out. Thank you for the clarification.